# How do I fix JavaHL (JNI) Not available after I have changed the logon password on my Mac?

Tags: eclipse, svn, macos, eclipse-plugin

I have installed Eclipse 3.5.2 and the plugin Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.6.9.2 and this worked without any problems. However, this morning I was forced to change the password to logon to my Mac and since then I get the message that "Subversion native library not available" when I try to save any changes. Can anyone help? I have tried to add this line (-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni) to the eclipse.ini file but this didn´t seem to make any difference.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh), then run the following command:

For [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), the commands to run are:

```
sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal
```

For [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh), the command is:

```
brew install --universal --java subversion
```

Comment: Is the --java flag for brew what adds the bindings? How to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  I suspect your libraries are there but just need permissions changed, whereas I didn't have the libs at all.

The directory to check is `/opt/subversion/lib`, see if it has any *libsvnjavahl* files.  In your case they may be there and just need new permissions.

To get the files I followed the the instructions they give for [installing JavaHL on OS X](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b), which is to download and install [Open CollabNet](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/). *(login required, although it's free)*

Then you just need to update your environment variable in *.profile*, something like:

> export PATH=.:/opt/subversion/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH

Then ran:

> .   .profile

Then I tested with [javahltests.jar](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-404019ac0784cfe12ca6de2581b8a6ac98896bde) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274890/javahl-not-loading-noclassdeferror/3276536#3276536).

Comment: You can also just create a symlink in /Library/Java/Extensions to the libjavahl library: `$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  40 Sep 23  2011 libsvnjavahl-1.jnilib -> /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog entry that gives a solution:
[http://blog.mattwoodward.com/getting-rid-of-subversion-native-library-not](http://web.archive.org/web/20100503135639/http://blog.mattwoodward.com/getting-rid-of-subversion-native-library-not)

I don't know whether this will work in your particular situation, but it's worth a try.

(Edited to fix link that became broken after I posted.  The link became broken sometime between May 3 and June 1.)

Comment: OP is asking in Mac OS X, not in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is download and install the OSX package that is provided on [openCollabNet](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/).

MacPorts also provides an easy Subversion and JavaHL package, however on Snow Leopard ?MacPorts is still compiling these packages as simple 32-bit binaries. If you use the default Snow Leopard JVM which is 64-bit you will get an error...

Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:

no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path 
/opt/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.0.0.dylib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /opt/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

**Note the error about wrong architecture. This is because the 64-bit JVM cannot load a 32-bit native library. The ?CollabNet binaries for OSX do not have this problem because they include both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.**

Source: [subclipse.tigris.org](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b)

Comment: There is no OSX package at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have subversion installed I'd recommend performing first a brew uninstall and then the install again. And follow the steps to create the links indicated after the install concludes. This worked for me. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it installing the ***SVNKit Client Adapter (not required)*** package.