# Eclipse, Subclipse 1.8.2, SVN 1.7.0 asks password every action

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

After I installed new **Eclipse Indigo**, it asks me for password every action I do in **SVN Repository** perspective (e.g. browse through every single folder ask password again).

Normally use **SVNKit**, it ask for password **once per session**. SVNKit doesn't support **SVN 1.7.0** yet.

How can I fix this or is it normal behavior of JavaHL?

**Note**: I don't want to save the password, but I want to enter the password once per session & repository. If I restart eclipse, I want to enter password again.

Settings:

- Eclipse Indigo SR1
- Subclipse 1.8.2
- SVN 1.7.0 (workspace)
- SVN Client: JavaHL 1.7.1

**Update**: [SVNKit 1.7.4](http://svnkit.com/) is now available.

Comment: Usually the profile is saved in the windows\document and settins folder, unless you already had one or deleted it manually. Sounds crazy but maybe a restart will help you to fix it?

Comment: I'm beyond restart (eclipse, computer). Doesn't fix it :(. Where can I find the profile file, what does it called?

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\[-YourWorkstationUserId-]\Application Data\Subversion

also please see http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/subclipse-setup.html#Set+Subversion+Preferences+in+Eclipse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The once per session caching is a feature that SVNKit provides.  JavaHL does not provide this.  It sounds like you do not allow SVN to cache your credentials or you are using svn+ssh:// in which case SVN cannot cache your credentials.  If it is the latter, you can store your SSH key on the server to avoid logging in and run ssh-agent on your client to provide the certificate to the SSH client.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info :). The repositories are using https://. Is the same as svn+ssh://?

Comment: Not the same. The issue is you do not cache passwords and JavaHl does not have any kind of session cache.

Comment: @Mark: where do I get the key file so I can put it on the server?

Answer (score 31):

For some reason, I had both SVNKit and JavaHL installed. I needed to update my Eclipse preferences to use SVNKit instead of JavaHL.

In Preferences > Team > SVN > SVN Interface 
switch:
JavaHL (JNI) ...
 
to:
SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit ....

Comment: That did it for me too.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Was just the reverse for me (from SVNKit to JavaHL) but did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For me this caused eclipse (Oxygen) to remember my password, but no svn commands would work anymore. Everytime I would try to commit/switch/merge it would show the progress bar and it would keep loading forever, had to kill eclipse to cancel the operation. switched back to JavaHL and solved the problem using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761737/2342529

Answer (score 3):

My observation (with Subclipse 1.6.13 and JavaHL 1.6.12 on Eclipse 3.7.1) is that Subclipse (even with the JavaHL connector) is able to cache the credentials if you create the repository connection in the "SVN Repositories" view.

When you create the the repository connection in the "Checkout projects from SVN" import wizard, the credentials will not get saved. In this case, they won't even get saved when recreating it in the "SVN Repositories" view until the next restart of Eclipse.

You can see if any credentials are saved by looking at the contents of the following folder: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion (on Windows 7). When any credentials are stored, an "auth" subdirectory exists in this directory.

Answer (score 2):

for svn+ssh create system variable: `SVN_SSH`

and set it like this:

```
C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe" -l user -pw password
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has the same problem with Kepler and Subversive (on Ubuntu), I was able to solve it by **checking 'UI Prompt'** in General -> Security -> Security Storage -> [Password]

Answer (score 0):

When first time I am facing the same problem I change my windows password and that worked.
Actually, in my company, we have the policy to change the password after every 3 months and my password was expired, so I was facing the problem.

The second time I just Restarted the eclipse that works for me.